# Take screenshot in Python -- Cross Platform

Tags: python, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot and send it via post to a web service. I think for the post part i will use liburl.

Can this be accomplished completely cross platform and without having the need for the final user to install additional libraries/software?

Comment: I think you could use wxpython. See Andrea Gavanas answer here: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-td2357826.html

Comment: but would my users need to install wxpython? or just by compiling the program the binary will work?

Comment: Python don't compile. It's run from the interpreter. But your right, they have to install wxpython which is pretty standard anyway if you don't bundle it with the install script...

Comment: @Carlos, you can pack python into an exe (http://www.py2exe.org/ or http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).  This allows you to pack both the python interpreter and any dependencies.

Comment: but an exe seems windows only, i think i will program something according to os, and then use specific os calls to take the screenshot

Comment: If you are using mac you can use the command `screencapture`.

Answer (score 10):

There is not anything in the standard library that can do this for you. Theoretically, you might do it yourself by making os-dependent system calls with ctypes but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work to me. Here is a working script to make a screenshot using wxPython:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)

s = wx.ScreenDC()
w, h = s.Size.Get()
b = wx.EmptyBitmap(w, h)
m = wx.MemoryDCFromDC(s)
m.SelectObject(b)
m.Blit(0, 0, w, h, s, 0, 0)
m.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
b.SaveFile("screenshot.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Comment: @Lipis There is no easy fix unfortunately, here is a discussion on the subject http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/ScreenDC-wxMac-td2358205.html

Comment: It does not take all windows, I have a program popup which is not on the screenshot.. weird.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use PyQt5 for this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()
desktopPixmap = screen.grabWindow(0)
desktopPixmap.save('screendump.png')
```

Comment: This works great on my Linux Mint Xfce 18.3, and Windows 7, thanks!

Comment: Any idea why this would suddenly stop giving me all monitors?