# Cross platform system screenshots

Tags: c, node.js, cross-platform, screenshot

I'm building a node-webkit app and want to be able to take screenshots of external apps that users are running. Is there a cross-platform (MIT or open source) solution for this? Perhaps there's a C library that can handle this and I can link it in my node app?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use python. python's Wx library you can make it cross platform.

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
s = wx.ScreenDC()
w, h = s.Size.Get()
b = wx.EmptyBitmap(w, h)
m = wx.MemoryDCFromDC(s)
m.SelectObject(b)
m.Blit(0, 0, w, h, s, 0, 0)
m.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
b.SaveFile("screenshot.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

It works great. In mac, wx and python both are installed by default. in linux you only need wx to install.In windows you have to install both. you can give it a try. [Answer is copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644908/take-screenshot-in-python-cross-platform)

Comment: Is there any way to take a screenshot of a single specific application?

Comment: in linux there is a option to the active windows screen shot. You take the active window geometry(x,y, height, width) then crop the image at that size.