# wxPython screenshot Windows

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, screenshot

I've got an (apparently) cross-platform screenshot function using wxPython:

```
def take_screenshot(x=0, y=0, width=None, height=None):
try:
    import wx
except ImportError as e:
    return 'Screenshot could not be taken - wx could not be imported: %s' %(e)
import os, datetime
folder_name = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S') + '.png'
directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'screenshots', folder_name)
make_directory(directory)
filename = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

app = wx.App()
screen = wx.ScreenDC()

size = screen.GetSize()
if width == None:
    width = size[0]
if height == None:
    height = size[1]
bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
mem.Blit(0, 0, width, height, screen, x, y)

del mem
bmp.SaveFile(filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
return 'Screenshot saved to file: %s' %(filename)
```

[Here is a screenshot I took on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt89u.png). This code works fine on Linux. I'm running on Python 2.7.8 and wxPython 3.0.2.0

Has anyone seen any similar problems? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed a few years ago on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644908/take-screenshot-in-python-cross-platform) and the [wxPython mailing list](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/ScreenDC-wxMac-td2358205.html). At that time, there was no reliable cross-platform method of taking a screenshot of the user's screen. I have not heard of any improvements since. You might try the PyQt method mentioned in the Stack link or you could try out the [pyscreenshot](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot) project.

Answer (score 0):

Update for **wxPython 4 and higher**

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
screen = wx.ScreenDC()

size = screen.GetSize()
width = size.width
height = size.height
bmp = wx.Bitmap(width, height)

# Create a memory DC that will be used for actually taking the screenshot
memDC = wx.MemoryDC()
# Tell the memory DC to use our Bitmap
# all drawing action on the memory DC will go to the Bitmap now
memDC.SelectObject(bmp)
# Blit (in this case copy) the actual screen on the memory DC
memDC.Blit(
    0, 0,
    width, height,
    screen,
    0, 0
)
# Select the Bitmap out of the memory DC by selecting a new bitmap
memDC.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
im = bmp.ConvertToImage()
im.SaveFile('screenshot.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```